# Merging pandas dataframe with an empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes:

df1

```
   2014  2015  2016  2017
NY   90    85    84    80
IL   88    79    72    65
VA   75    76    81    79
MD   60    62    66    70
```

df2

```
   Empty DataFrame
   Columns: []
   Index: [CA, WA, NY, VA, DE, MD, IL]
```

How can I get the following dataframe using the two above?

```
   2014  2015  2016  2017
CA   -1    -1    -1    -1
WA   -1    -1    -1    -1
NY   90    85    84    80
VA   75    76    81    79
DE   -1    -1    -1    -1
MD   60    62    66    70
IL   88    79    72    65
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by index of `df2`:

```
df = df1.reindex(df2.index, fill_value=-1)
print (df)
    2014  2015  2016  2017
CA    -1    -1    -1    -1
WA    -1    -1    -1    -1
NY    90    85    84    80
VA    75    76    81    79
DE    -1    -1    -1    -1
MD    60    62    66    70
IL    88    79    72    65
```